# How do I prevent the console from appearing when building a Windows SDL project with Eclipse?

Tags: windows, eclipse, console, sdl

When you run the .exe, the SDL window appears, but so does a console window. How do I get just the SDL window by itself?

What configuration option should I be changing? Is there one?

I'm compiling with MinGW and using Eclipse Ganymede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to compile with

-Wl,-subsystem,windows

as a linker flag.

Mmm, answerin' my own questions.